# Google Sheet go to sheets shortcut

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to go to a original cell from shortcut.
Ex: I used a formula to get a total sum from selected cells `=SUM(Sheet2!A2:A5)` but when I'm in sheet 1 how to to go to Sheet A2 A5 with shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @PgSystemTester answer,  you can use either a named range, or just the cell reference.

`Sheet1!A2`

[image]

Comment: agreed, thanks for adding. I should have included. Question: Are you as bored as I am right now due to FN being down? 12 hour seems way to long... I don't know what to do with myself.

Comment: Lol. No, I was watching football and talking smack with my fantasy team.

Answer (score 2):

On Sheet1, you can create a link to anywhere in the spreadsheet using the insert link function and then specifying the destination. I would use a named range as a destination in case you insert rows/columns.

[image]

[image]